# Node JS Fetching JSON from url is executing AFTER the rest of the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I wanted to get a JSON from a URL in my node JS code. The code is working fine, but the sequence of the execution is messed up because of the Async nature of the execution.

```
var http = require("https");

var number = 37302;

// these functions need to execute is sequence.    

console.log('Before API Call');

var response = fetchJson(number);
console.log(response);

console.log('After API Call');  



function fetchJson(number)
{        

    var url = 'https://example.com/api/getactionitems/' + number;

    http.get(url, function(res){
        var body = ''; 

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk; 
            console.log('JSON Retrieved.');               
        });

        res.on('end', function(){

            console.log('Parsing JSON');

            var APIResponse = JSON.parse(body);

            var Name = APIResponse.EmpName;
            var outstring = APIResponse.ActionItem;                
            return ('Hi ' + Name + ', Your action Items are: '+ outstring);            
        });
    })
    .on('error', function(e){
      return ("Got an error while fetching data.");
    });

}
```

When this code executes, the sequence of the output strings are as follows:

```
Before API Call
undefined
After API Call
JSON Retrieved.
Parsing JSON
```

How can I correct the execution order, so that the sequence are like the following:

```
Before API Call
JSON Retrieved.
Parsing JSON
<Outpt from the JSON parsing>
After API Call
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var http = require("https");

var number = 37302;

// these functions need to execute is sequence.    


console.log('Before API Call');

fetchJson(number).then(function(res){

console.log(res);

console.log('After API Call');
}).catch(function(e){console.log('err',e)});



function fetchJson(number)
{        
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    var url = 'https://example.com/api/getactionitems/' + number;

    http.get(url, function(res){
        var body = ''; 

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk; 
            console.log('JSON Retrieved.');               
        });

        res.on('end', function(){

            console.log('Parsing JSON');

            var APIResponse = JSON.parse(body);

            var Name = APIResponse.EmpName;
            var outstring = APIResponse.ActionItem;                
            resolve('Hi ' + Name + ', Your action Items are: '+ outstring);            
        });
    })
    .on('error', function(e){
      reject("Got an error while fetching data.");
    });
});

}
```

Comment: Hi Shirish, thanks but this solution does not print the 'After API Call' string for some reason.

Comment: what console.log did you get at the end "Got an error while fetching data." or 'Hi ' + Name + ', Your action Items are: '+ outstring

Comment: I am getting this error:
TypeError: res is not a function
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (d:\Development\NodeJSProjects\assistant.js:42:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again :-( but the response is coming like this now.

Before API Call
JSON Retrieved.
Parsing JSON
Promise { <pending> }
After API Call

Comment: i edited the answer again, i am sure this gonna work